# how to select two unique field's results and display as one column of result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two fields includes and excludes, I want to extract the unique data among them and display the result as one column of result.
for example, the includes and excludes have same possible values like lunch, dinner, wifi. the result should be like,
excludesAndIncludes
(unique results among excludes and includes)
.....................
lunch
dinner
wifi
etc

Comment: sample data and the expected results please.

Comment: includes: dinner, wifi, lunch
excludes:dinner, wifi, lunch, breakfast

expected result:
includesAndExcludes:wifi, lunch, breakfast, dinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union`:

```
select excludes as excludesAndIncludes from t
union
select includes from t;
```

Comment: @kartik . . . This returns a unique list of values, which is what the question asks for:  "unique results among excludes and includes".

Answer (score 0):

You can write query like this:

```
select DISTINCT x.excludesAndIncludes from
(select DISTINCT excludes as excludesAndIncludes from t
union
select DISTINCT includes as excludesAndIncludes from t) as x;
```

Comment: may be this should work. i will mark this as right answer if that is going to work.